# Can you balance this poker deck?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, cards, poker

You are given the digits 0 to 9 in 4 poker suits.

Distribute them onto the 8 highest poker hands (make one of each) of 5 digits each. They are

- Royal Flush (9 to 5 of one suit)
- Straight Flush (consecutive digits of one suit)
- Full House (3 identical + 2 identical)
- Four of a Kind (4 identical)
- Straight (5 consecutive)
- Flush (5 of the same suit)
- Three of a Kind (3 identical)
- Two Pair (2 identical + 2 identical)

Can you do that so the sum of the digits in each poker hand is at least 17?

Bonus: Can you do the same with a 3 in the Four of a Kind hand?

Comment: Each hand is valued by the sum of the values you chose for the corresponding cards

Comment: Because you have to distribute the deck to the different poker hands? But sorry if I used the wrong tag for this question

Comment: Oh i see now what you meant. We have to make exactly one of each of the hands

Comment: Nah I'm just slow sometimes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a partition where all hands are at least 17:

> 9♤8♤7♤6♤5♤ royal flush
>  7♧6♧5♧4♧3♧ straight flush
>  2♤2♡2◇2♧9♧ four of a kind
>  0♤0◇0♧9♡9◇ full house
>  8♡5♡3♡1♡0♡ flush
>  8♧7◇6◇5◇4◇ straight
>  1♤1◇1♧8◇6♡ three of a kind
>  4♤4♡3♤3◇7♡ two pair

Here is a partition with a 3 in the four of a kind hand:

> 9♤8♤7♤6♤5♤ royal flush
>  5♧4♧3♧2♧1♧ straight flush
>  0♤0♡0◇0♧3◇ four of a kind
>  6♡6◇6♧7◇7♧ full house
>  7♡5♡3♡2♡1♡ flush
>  5◇4◇3♤2◇1◇ straight
>  8♡8◇8♧9♧1♤ three of a kind
>  9♡9◇4♤4♡2♤ two pair

There are no partitions where all hands sum to at least 18 or that satisfy both the restrictions above. [This is an exact cover problem](https://gist.github.com/Parcly-Taxel/e27e101fd7c9dc6a59ff281dbe38bfc6); this is how the solutions above were found.

---

All hands at least 16 and 3 in the four of a kind:

> 9♤8♤7♤6♤5♤ royal flush
>  8♧7♧6♧5♧4♧ straight flush
>  3♤3♡3◇3♧5◇ four of a kind
>  0♤0◇0♧9◇9♧ full house
>  7♡6♡2♡1♡0♡ flush
>  8◇7◇6◇5♡4◇ straight
>  2♤2◇2♧9♡1♧ three of a kind
>  4♤4♡1♤1◇8♡ two pair

Comment: Nice! Can you get to at least 16 on all hands for the bonus question?

Comment: @Nurator added.