# All poker hands from a single deck

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, computer-puzzle, cards, poker

This question suggested itself to me – and I found a solution – after I solved [Can you balance this poker deck?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/125902/75318).

Take out two aces from the standard 52-card deck. Your challenge is to partition the remaining 50 cards into ten poker hands, one each of all the popularly recognised types:

- Royal flush
- Straight flush that is not a royal flush
- Four of a kind
- Full house
- Flush
- Straight
- Three of a kind
- Two pair
- One pair
- High card

In addition, your solution must satisfy two more constraints.

- The seven non-flush hands **must each use all four suits**.
- The sum of card values in each hand must be at least **34**, counting 2s to 10s as face value, jacks as 11, queens as 12, kings as 13 and aces as 14.

Good luck.

Comment: Does the first condition apply to each and every one of those seven remaining hands, or just all of them combined must use all four suits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would work

> Royal flush:  10S, JS, QS, KS, AS
>  Straight flush: 7C, 8C, 9C, 10C, JC
>  Four of a Kind: 5C, 5D, 5H, 5S, AC
>  Full House: 3C 3H 3S KD KH
>  Flush: 2D 6D 7D 9D JD
>  Straight: 6C 7S 8H 9H 10D
>  Three of a Kind: 4C 4D 4S 10H QH
>  Two pair: QC QD 2H 2S 6H
>  One pair: 8D 8S 2C 7H 9S
>  High Card: 3D 4H 6S JH KC

Answer (score 2):

My own solution:

> Royal flush: AS KS QS JS 10S
>  Straight flush: 10C 9C 8C 7C 6C
>  Four of a kind: 5S 5H 5D 5C AC
>  Full house: 3S 3D 3C KH KD
>  Flush: QH JH 6H 3H 2H
>  Straight: JC 10H 9S 8D 7D
>  Three of a kind: 4S 4H 4C QD 10D
>  Two pair: 7S 7H 6S 6D QC
>  One pair: 2S 2D KC 9D 8H
>  High card: JD 9H 8S 4D 2C
>  [image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I enjoyed working this out.
Based on card images linked by @EricDuminil on SE's [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51426/where-can-i-download-high-quality-images-of-poker-cards).
I removed the Aces of Hearts and Clubs.

> Here is my first solution
>
>  [image]
>
>  I found 1760 solutions before my C program crashed :)